# What does lars return for lambda equal to zero when p is larger than n?

Tags: regression, lasso, lars

For the lasso problem
$$
\hat \beta(\lambda) = \underset{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p}{\operatorname{argmin}}\|Y - X \beta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_1,
$$
where $Y$ is $p \times 1$, $X$ is $n \times p$, it is clear that when $p < n$, we have 
$$
\hat \beta(0) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY.
$$
The lars algorithm with the lasso modification returns a sequence of tuning parameter values $\lambda_1 >\dots>\lambda_M >0$ along with the corresponding lasso solutions $\hat \beta(\lambda_1),\dots,\hat\beta(\lambda_M)$ as well as, in the case in which $p < n$, the least-squares estimator $\hat \beta(0)$.

Now, in the case in which $p\geq n$, the algorithm likewise returns a sequence of tuning parameter values $\lambda_1 >\dots>\lambda_M >0$ along with the corresponding solutions $\hat \beta(\lambda_1),\dots,\hat\beta(\lambda_M)$ as well as *another* value of the estimator $\hat \beta(?)$.

My question is: to what value of the tuning parameter $\lambda$ does this additional value of the estimator correspond when $p \geq n$?  In the $p<n$ case it corresponds to $\lambda = 0$, but in the $p \geq n$ case, the lasso estimator is undefined for $\lambda = 0$, so it cannot correspond to this.  If it corresponds to some other value of $\lambda$, why is this value not returned?

The R code below gives an example:

```r
library(lars)

# Generate some data with n > p
n <- 12
p <- 10
p0 <- 3
X <- scale(matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p), center=TRUE)
beta <- c(rep(1,p0),rep(0,p-p0))
Y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(n)

# Run the lars algorithm
lars.out <- lars(y = Y, x = X, type = "lasso", intercept = FALSE)

# View the solutions at knot points in the path
coef(lars.out)

# Print the sequence of lambda values. 
# There is no lambda value corresponding to the final row:
lars.out$lambda

# Compute the least-squares estimator: 
# It is the same as the final row of coef(lars.out)
solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
```

So far so good.  But if we consider the case in which $p \geq n$ we have

```r
# Generate some data with n >= p
n <- 8
p <- 10
p0 <- 3
X <- scale(matrix(rnorm(n*p),n,p), center=TRUE)
beta <- c(rep(1,p0),rep(0,p-p0))
Y <- X %*% beta + rnorm(n)

# Run the lars algorithm
lars.out <- lars(y = Y, x = X, type = "lasso", intercept = FALSE)

# View the solutions at knot points in the path
coef(lars.out)

# Print the sequence of lambda values. 
# There is no lambda value corresponding to the final row:
lars.out$lambda
```

How is the last row of `coef(lars.out)` computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the answer is that it's the minimum $\ell_1$ norm least squares estimator. This was shown in Lemma 7 of:

> Tibshirani, R. J. (2013). The lasso problem and uniqueness. Electronic Journal of Statistics, 7, 1456-1490.

In order to quickly see why, all we need to take for granted is that the LARS (with lasso modification) coefficient path is continuous and is supported at $\lambda = 0$. Write $\hat{\beta}_\lambda$ as the LARS estimator for regularization parameter $\lambda$ in the lasso problem with objective $\|y - X \beta\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\beta\|_1$. When $\lambda = 0$, we know that $\hat{\beta}_0$ is a least squares estimator. Which one, though??

Let $\tilde{\beta}$ be any least squares estimator and $\lambda \geq 0$. From the definition, we know that $$\|y - X \hat{\beta}_\lambda\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\hat{\beta}_\lambda\|_1 \leq \|y - X \tilde{\beta}\|_2^2 + \lambda \|\tilde{\beta}\|_1.$$ However, since the least squares estimator provides the closest fit, we know that $\|y - X \hat{\beta}_\lambda\|_2^2 \geq \|y - X \tilde{\beta}\|_2^2,$ which makes $$\|\hat{\beta}_\lambda\|_1 \leq \|\tilde{\beta}\|_1.$$ Taking a limit $\lambda \to 0$ of this inequality, we find that the LARS estimator $\hat{\beta}_0$ has $\ell_1$ norm no bigger than any least squares estimator.